# need variable text to appear on every page of rendered WORD document in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-server, rstudio-server

I have been on a search for the past 3 months for a way to be able to show a text on every page of the document. Note that I want this text to be changing so I can't just affix this as a header or a footer. Essentially I want something like this.

[image: Example of desired output 1]

The words "XYZ Corp." and "Version:" shall remain constant and shall appear on all pages and "A" would be dependent on a user input thru shiny UI.

Let's say the user input for `params$version` was B then this should be the output for all the pages of the rendered document.

[image: Example of desired output 2]

I have read everything about using a reference document and yes, I am using a reference document on my actual code to actually format the contents of my word doc. However, no matter how much I try to edit one of the 'heading styles' to make it look like an actual header just like how I wanted to be, I am unsuccessful to have it appear on multiple pages of the document. Essentially, if I edit the styles and have:

```
cat("#", "XYZ Corp.", "                ", paste("Version:", params$version))
```

I am only able to have the output in the first page of the document but unsuccessful to have it appear on the succeeding documents.

**TL;DR**: **Ideally I want to be able to edit the headers dynamically by being able to edit it through user input.** However, if that is not possible, I am thinking that maybe there is a way to be able to print certain pieces of text on the word document that is to be rendered.

Comment: Have you had any luck solving this issue since you posted the question?